# A WordPress loop that displays the latest post from just 4 of your categories

Tags: php, html, wordpress, php-7.1

I'm a WP beginner and I have written a loop that is displaying the latest post from each of my categories, but I need to refine the loop so it only displays the latest post from 4 different categories. Can anyone help me restrict the number of categories im looping through? it would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="latest-updates-container container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="latest-update-text">
                LATEST UPDATES
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="latest-updates-outter-wrapper"></div>
    <!--/.container-->
    <div class="">
        <?php

    $do_not_duplicate = array();
    $categories = get_categories();

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        $args = array(
            'cat' => -2,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
        );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>

        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

            $query->the_post();
            $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;
    if($i % 5 == 0) { ?>

        <div class="row latest-post">

            <?php
}
?>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="my-inner">
                    <h5 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="blog-heading">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"
                            title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
                            <?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h5>
                    <div class="time-read-now"><?php echo reading_time(); ?>&nbsp; &#183;&nbsp;
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to">read now</a></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $i++;
  if($i != 0 && $i % 5 == 0) { ?>
        </div>
        <!--/.row-->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <?php
   } ?>

        <?php } // end while ?>

        </section>

        <?php } // end if

// Use reset to restore original query.
wp_reset_postdata();
    }
?>
    </div>

</div>
</div>

</div>

Its displaying the latest post from all categories, I need to just display 4 categories.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cat` parameter allows you to [filter posts by category ID](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters). Your code is almost correct, all you need to do now is pass the category ID to the `WP_Query` class:

```
<?php

$do_not_duplicate = array();
$categories = get_categories();

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $args = array(
        'cat' => $category->term_id, // Get posts from this category ID
        'category__not_in' => array(4, 2), // Exclude posts from categories 4 and 2
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Rest of your code here...
```

Comment: Hey @cabrerahector, thanks for getting back to me. I've added this line to the WP_Query class and now its showing multiple posts. rather then removing a category ID, am i missing something? many thanks 

        `$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '-4,-2' ) );`

Comment: Of course, you need to include the `post_per_page` parameter as well, like in the example, to limit the query to 1 post per category.

Comment: Make sure to copy the rest of the parameters as well.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had included that in my  $args array. When I try exclude categories 4 and 2 they still appear. Any more help would be much appreciated. ive been looking at this loop for hours, ha :)

Comment: So i need to include $args in my WP_Query class and i also need to include an array to exclude the categories?

Comment: To exclude categories, you can use the `category__not_in` parameter. If you want to exclude categories 4 and 2, then add this: `"category__not_in" => array(4, 2)`.

Comment: Have a look at the code above, I just edited it to show you how to use that parameter.

Comment: Hi Cabrerahector, I figured this out last night. thanks for all your help